# How to remove elements in a vector that match some element in another vector

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++14

I want to remove elements in a vector `v2` that match the elements in another vector `v1`, where each element in `v1` has a corresponding element in `v2` but not vice versa.

My idea is to use `std::vector::erase`, `std::remove_if` and `std::find` like this:

```
std::vector<int> v1{ 6, 2, 4 };
std::vector<int> v2{ 8, 2, 9, 4, 5, 3, 7, 1, 6 };

v2.erase(
  std::remove_if(v2.begin(), v2.end()
  , [&v1](auto& item)
  {
    return std::find(v1.begin(), v1.end(), item) != v1.end();
  })
);
```

Which works.  However, I wonder if I could do without matching those that have already been matched as this is a 1:1 relationship when going from `v1 -> v2`.  `v1` will be blown away afterwards, so it can be modified.

Comment: can you sort the vectors first?

Comment: @UKMonkey, not `v2`. You can do anything to `v1`.  `v2` is not necessarily sorted.

Comment: If v1 is not extremely large, you should transform it into a std::unordered_set, make use of that 0(1) complexity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sort v1.  Use std equal range to find elements in it.  Use that with your remove-erase idiom code (with a bugfix).

This is O((M+N)lg N)

```
std::sort( v1.begin(), v1.end() );
auto removed=std::remove_if(
  v2.begin(), v2.end(), 
  [&v1](auto& item)
  {
    auto r= std::equal_range(v1.begin(), v1.end(), item);
    return r.first!=r.second;
  }
);
v2.erase(removed, v2.end());
```

note that you forgot `.end` in your erase call, which is a common serious error when doing remove-erase.

Editing the source vector to eliminate elements is not worth it if you have a reasonable number of entries, barring extremely fancy data structures.

Comment: Doh!  Yeah, missed that bug.

Comment: Um, doesn't `equal_range` require that `v1` is sorted?

Comment: @Adrian if you can't sort v1, create a vector of indexes into v1 and sort that based on the value of v1

Comment: @UKMonkey, yeah, I know that, but the answer is incomplete without that bit.

Comment: @Adrian The first sentence is "sort v1" in this answer?

Comment: Ah, missed that. :)

Comment: Rethinking this, I think that it would be better for the lambda to read: `[&v1](auto& item) { auto found = std::lower_bound(v1.begin(), v1.end, item); return found != v1.end() && !(item < *found); }` because we don't have to compute both ends of the range.  I wrote it using `operator <()` because I want to show a more general solution.  This modification would prolly result in code that is about twice as fast.

Comment: @Adrian Finding upper bound once you have lower bound tends to not take as long.  Esp when calculating both at once, because most of the branches are similar.

Comment: If both are done at one, then yes, it would prolly be faster then twice the speed when using the lambda I suggested, but still would be slower as the number of operations would be more. It would also depend on how expensive the `operator<()` is as the number of comparisons would be double. How much slower is TBD.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve linear complexity for solving your problem but with extra memory.  You can transfer the first vector to hash (unordered_set). So as result you get O(N) complexity ( excluding efforts for creating hash )

```
std::vector<int> v1{ 6, 2, 4 };
std::vector<int> v2{ 8, 2, 9, 4, 5, 3, 7, 1, 6 };

std::unordered_set<int> hash_v1( v1.begin(), v1.end() );

// linear complexity for remove_if
v2.erase( std::remove_if( v2.begin(), v2.end(), [&hash_v1] ( auto& item )
{
    return hash_v1.find( item ) != hash_v1.end(); // constant time
}), v2.end());
```

And do not forget about **v2.end()** as second parameter for ease method.

Comment: Nice. A bit overkill for my application.  Still good to see alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to modify `v1`, then something like the following would work:

```
v2.erase(
  std::remove_if(v2.begin(), v2.end(),
    [&v1](auto& item) {
      auto it = std::find(v1.begin(), v1.end(), item);
      if (it != v1.end()) {
        v1.erase(it);
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
  ), v2.end());
```

**Edit 1:** Sort `v1` first, then use `std::lower_bound` for O(log n) search speed instead of O(n).

**Edit 2:** Store `v1`'s elements into an `std::unordered_set` to make erase and find O(1) amortized instead.

**Edit 3:** Added bugfix regarding `erase` as mentioned by Yakk.

Comment: Yeah, but the erase is a O(N) operation.

Comment: @Adrian Yes, I know, this was just a quick and dirty solution :). If I figure out something better, I'll update accordingly (unless someone beats me to it). You could of course always copy `v1` into e.g. an `unordered_set`, that would make removal and find both O(1).